# Custom .blend file completely not working as expected

Tags: customization, startup-file, template

So I created a custom .blend file, named it "startup.blend" and put it into a custom-named folder in the `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.3\3.3\scripts\startup\bl_app_templates_system` folder (BTW, I've also tried this same thing with version 3.4.1 as well with all the same results).

When I create a new file, I get a menu with all the regular default startup files as well as my custom startup file. Which seems right. And when I choose my custom startup file, it opens. Also seems right.

But here's where it gets weird. When I choose ANY of the other choices (General, 2D Animation, Sculpting) instead of opening the appropriate template, it opens up my custom template! I know I didn't accidentally put the custom blend file into all 4 of the default folders because if I choose `Open` from the `File` menu and navigate to each of the startup template files and open them that way, the templates look as expected.

And here's where it gets even weirder. If I shut down Blender and remove my custom folder from the `bl_app_templates_system` folder completely and restart Blender, all of the startup files STILL open my custom template!

Why is this happening? Shouldn't I be able to customize the blend files in that folder without this weirdness happening? And how is it finding my custom startup file even after I completely remove it from the folder?

Comment: I would check the user preference files in your home directory. On Windows, it's *%APPDATA%\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.4\config* A startup file that you create via the menu entry *File > Defaults > Save Startup File* is saved in this folder.

Comment: Ahhh... that was it, thanks! Looks like my new template files were being overridden by the ones in that folder.